# Regular expression for name

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need an regular expression to match the account logins.

The symbols I would like to match:

> ```
> Test
> testtest
> Special Char Testó
> Special Char Test
> Test Test
> Hai hai
> Test-ó
> Test.ó
> Testó
> Another Test 12345
> Another.Test.12345
> ```

The closest regular expression I have find is: `^(?=[^ ])[a-zA-Z0-9 +&-]+(?<=\S)$`. But it still doesn't match all of the above examples.

Live preview: http://regexr.com?30ncg

Here are all symbols it shouldnt match:

```
Test?
Test$
Test= (and all special characters like those @#$%^&*=).
Test[]
Test>
Test<
```

- so its basicly working find, but it doesnt match the word like `Another.Test.12345` or `Special Char Testó`.

I want it to match only a word characters (including special ones like `ółążźćęą` and `äöüß`), numbers, dots and spaces.

I've been searching a lot , but didnt find any better regex than this one in the example given above.

Comment: I cant understand what exactly you want to match here? Just all symbols? Give me example what you dont need to match.

Comment: `The symbols I would like to match:` ... just all of them.

Comment: I don't understand how this question has three upvotes already -- you need to elaborate on what you're trying to achieve. What is your input set? What *exactly* are you trying to match? All you've said so far is "I want to match all symbols." So, you're looking for `(.*)`?

Comment: I agree with @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ - it might be easier if you tell us what you *don't* want to match...

Comment: Interesting that you use the same regexr link as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249538/regular-expression-for-name) question, asked by another user...

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ I don't understand you comment, I just want to regular expression, which will match each symbol. It should match: words, words with dots, words with numbers words with spaces... just the examples I gave.

Comment: @Cyclone `.+` will match all of those, but it will also (I guess) match stuff you don't want to match. Like I say, what should be excluded?

Comment: @DaveRandom Ok, sorry, I will edit my answer within a minute.

Comment: http://regexr.com?30ncg Here are all symbols it shouldnt match - so its basicly working find, but it doesnt match the word like `Another.Test.12345` or `Special Char Testó`.

Comment: You want a regex that will match *any* symbol?  Okay, here you go: `/./`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249538/regular-expression-for-name

Comment: Not devious, just wondering why you're posting the same question under separate logins.

Comment: @ceejayoz , Same question? I would argue.

Comment: With the exact same specific test cases? Sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match just characters that you listed in your question, then you should use this regex:

```
/(?:\A|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\&\-ółążźćęąäöüß\.\s]))([a-zA-Z0-9\+\&\-ółążźćęąäöüß\.\s]+)(?:(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\&\-ółążźćęąäöüß\.\s])|\z)/
```

---

However, as the question is kind of unclear for me (and a lot of other users), I would like to suggest you to use a regex that would match all "letter class" single code unicode characters and some of your special characters. Such regex would then be:

```
/(?:\A|(?<=[^\p{L}\+\-\&\.\s]))([\p{L}\+\-\&\.\s]+)(?:(?=[^\p{L}\+\-\&\.\s])|\z)/
```

Comment: Looks pretty good! Thank you.

Comment: What about other non-ASCII unicode characters?

Comment: @JackManey - I put to regex set of characters that OP is asking for to match, so can you please be more specific what you mean or what you are suggesting? Thank you.

Comment: It's still not terribly clear what the OP wants to match...

Comment: @JackManey - You are right, we all feel it that way - I just added a suggestion for him in my (updated) answer. Does that look better for you now?

Comment: @stackoverflow http://regexr.com?30ncv your second example doesn't work there I don't really know what is unclear for you because I have made an update on what should be match and what shouldnt. Your first example is working fine (http://regexr.com?30nd2) but as Jack Maney is saying, it unfortunately wont work for all non-ASCII unicode characters. You've received an upvote for now, thank you :).

Comment: @briandfoy - Can you please take a look on this answer and find what is wrong in regex? I cannot find a problem there and I would appreciate your opinion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**[Note]**
I didn't read your edit before I posted this.

I assume you're using PHP. This worked for me:

```
$a = 'Test
testtest
Special Char TestóááÓ
Special Char Testß
Test Test
Hai hai
Test-ó
Test.ó
Testó
Another Test 12345
Another.Test.12345';

preg_match_all('/^(?=[^ ])[\w \.-\p{L}]+$/m', $a, $ms);

var_dump($ms);
```

It matched all lines. `\p{L}` will match unicode characters as read on http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: Actually `\p{L}` would match a lot of characters the OP didn't ask to -it would match all **"letter"** class unicode single code characters, so for example all Spanish latin characters, French, Italian, etc...

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP, but why it doesnt not work here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?30nc4 ?